# Refrescar JtextArea

Tags: java, java-swing

Buen día, Tengo un código en java que envía datos a un JtextArea el problema es que al volver a ejecutar el método y enviar otros datos se muestra bien los datos nuevos, pero al seleccionarlos en el jtextArea me muestra los que envié por primera vez.

De antemano gracias por la atencion prestada

[image: Primeros datos enviados]

[image: Segundos datos enviados]

[image: Al al tratar de seleccionarlos me muestra los primeros datos]

Adjunto fragmeto codigo

```
btnCalcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                calculadora nuevo = new calculadora();
                // Capturamos datos
                double pcompra= Double.parseDouble(txtCompra.getText());
                nuevo.setDatoUsuario(pcompra);
                double pestimado=Double.parseDouble(txtPorcentaje.getText());
                nuevo.setPorcentajeEstimado(pestimado);
                //Ejecutamos el metodo
                nuevo.calculo();
                //Creamos el JTextArea
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                frmCalcucripto.getContentPane().add(textArea);
                textArea.setEditable(true);
                textArea.setBounds(10, 150, 245,90);
                textArea.setBackground(new Color(0,150,136));
                textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                textArea.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
                //Enviamos los datos al JTextArea
                textArea.setText("Precio inicial: "+txtCompra.getText()+"\n"+"Porcentaje estimado: "+txtPorcentaje.getText()+" %"+"\n"+"Porcentaje calculado: "
                +nuevo.getDatoRedondeado()+"\n"+"Precio final: "+nuevo.getDatoFinal()); 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha presentado una anomalía en los datos ingresados:  "+e.getMessage());
            }           
        }
```

Comment: En el textArea tienes unos datos y cuando seleccionas con el puntero automáticamente se modifican por otros?

Comment: Correcto se modifican por los primeros que envie.

Comment: Eso es raro. Intenta limpiando el `textArea` antes de pasarle los datos. Coloca esta sentencia `textArea.setText("");` debajo debajo del comentario `//Enviamos los datos al JTextArea`.

Comment: David realize lo que me dijiste pero seguia igual, la solucion fue la que menciono Fernando, Pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que llamas al metodo creas un nuevo JtextArea, prueba a crearlo solo la primera vez que lo llamas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, implemente el formulario fuera del metodo y funciona genial.

Comment: @Dicruz de nada, saludos.